# VBA: If a string in column A does not contain a specific string, put a string in column B next to corresponding cells

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to check a string in column 1 of an intelligent table that consits of 6 columns if it does not contain specific strings using INSTR. If so, then I would like to put a defined string (for example "MC") only in column 2 next to the corresponding cells from column 1.

With the following code it puts "MC" not only in the column next to column 1, but in 6 columns next to column 1. It seems that my function uses the amount of columns whithin the DataBodyRange (which is 6) and adds them behind the Offset to column1.

How can I put the string "MC" only in 1 of 6 column?

```
Sub MyFunction()

Dim rngConfigCodeTbl  As Range
Const MnS3 As String = "MnS1"
Const MnS3 As String = "MnS2"

Set rngConfigCodeTbl = xlsReferences.ListObjects("tblConfigCode").DataBodyRange

For Each rngConfigCodeTbl In rngConfigCodeTbl
    If InStr(rngConfigCodeTbl, MnS1) = 0 Or InStr(rngConfigCodeTbl, MnS2) = 0 Then rngConfigCodeTbl.Offset(0, 1) = "MC"
Next rngConfigCodeTbl

End Sub
```

Comment: You are checking **all** columns of the table instead of only the cells of column 1. Use this code instead: `Set rngConfigCodeTbl = xlsReferences.ListObjects("tblConfigCode").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange`

Comment: Since your original column and your output column are both in a table, you might consider just doing this with a calculated column formula. You can use the worksheet functions `SEARCH` or `FIND` for the same purpose as VBA `InStr`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your feedback. At **Ike**: Your suggestion makes sense, so I have adopted it by taking FunThomas's code. At **kevin**: I decided to use VBA because the number of cells to check will increase over time and I will only run this subroutine from time to time when new data is added. I don't want to use too many formulas as VBA code is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point is your If-condition: You are checking if the cell value doesn't contain `MnS1` **OR** doesn't contain `MnS2`. That means unless you have a cell that contain *both* strings, either the first or the second part of the condition is true.

You will simply need to change the `Or` to an `And`: Write something in the neighbor cell if the cell neither contains `MnS1` nor `MnS2`.

There are 2 other things that should be fixed in your code: You declare (twice) the constant `MnS3` (that gives, btw, a compile error), but you are accessing constants `MnS1` and `MnS2` in your code which are not declared.

And while `For Each rngConfigCodeTbl In rngConfigCodeTbl` surprisingly works, you should use a different run variable in the `For`-Loop:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MySub()
    Dim rngConfigCodeTbl  As Range, cell As Range
    Const MnS1 As String = "MnS1"
    Const MnS2 As String = "MnS2"
    
    Set rngConfigCodeTbl = xlsReferences.ListObjects("tblConfigCode").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    
    For Each cell In rngConfigCodeTbl
        If InStr(cell, MnS1) = 0 And InStr(cell, MnS2) = 0 Then cell.Offset(0, 1) = "MC"
    Next cell 
End Sub
```

And you shouldn't name a Subroutine `MyFunction` - it is not a function, it's a subroutine.

**Update**: Ike (in the comments) is right, you probably want to check only one column. I updated the code.

Comment: Thank you so much FunThomas! Now the code works pefect. I changed Or to And, because you are absolutely right with what you wrote. Also thanks for the notes about the twice declaration of the constant. This was actually a stupid copy paste error when I wrote the question. All in all, I learned something again. Have a nice day :)